# What kind of objects should be under ioc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control

I'm building a web app using Spring and Spring MVC and I want to use as clean design as possible. I've studied dependency injection and inversion control but I don't still totally get it. Is it good practice to almost always avoid creating new objects and inject those instead? I understand that service and DAO objects are good to inject but in what cases one should just create a new instance?

Comment: Instance creation can some times be a heavy process especially when Spring needs to apply post processing, proxying, etc. If the object doesn't need to be managed by Spring (no injection targets, no proxying, no AOP), then just create it yourself.

Comment: A singleton object is also good choice for injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is no right answer. IMHO important signs of a good candidate for a Spring bean are

- Lives almost as long as the application (or scope)
- Needs things like security, transaction management etc. that are ideally handled by AOP
- Is a singleton (better said: has only one instance per scope)
- Does not change after instantiation

Controllers, services and repositories e.g. share these characteristics.

Answer (score 4):

Some examples of objects I would personally not manage with Spring:

- [Domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) - usually they are short lived object having their lifecycle managed by a persistence framework such as Hibernate and does not have dependencies on Service/DAO objects
- [Value objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueObject) and [Data transfer objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)
- Objects I would like to create with my own factory - I prefer having the logic of which type of object to create within the factory. Spring can manage the factory itself.
- Anything created for internal usage within a class or an application layer

In general I would not use Spring for managing object in cases where:

- The object does not have dependencies on other beans managed by Spring
- Spring will not help me with testing this object
- It does not require any resources managed by Spring such as data-sources, transactions, scheduler etc.
- I do not need Spring to decorate it with additional behavior
- When it badly hurts the readability of my code
- It is a short lived object, containing state and no logic

Answer (score 1):

A decent rule of thumb is that if an object is a dependency of more than one other object, it might be wise to make it a bean so that Spring can wire in an appropriate instance.

That said, Spring favors *singleton* beans, and honestly that seems like a relic of the past, as acquiring the lock for a singleton is likely much more expensive than just creating a new instance when it's needed. So, I wouldn't make any bean singleton-scoped unless it has state that actually needs to persist between usages of that object.